# proj.4 definition for (obsolete) UK War Office "Italy South" grid

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, proj

I'm helping a friend convert his late father's war diary coordinates to WGS84. I have a proj.4 definition that appears to work in QGIS, but if I transform a scanned map with gdalwarp, it's not even close. What am I doing wrong with my CRS definition, please?

Coordinates were given in the [Modified British System](http://www.echodelta.net/mbs/eng-welcome.php), which is a variant of the OSGB grid, but extended over several zones in Europe. Projection parameters (given to me by the linked site's author) are as follows:

```
Projection - Lambert Conical Orthomorphic
Ellipsoid: Bessel 1841
False Easting : 700000
False Northing : 600000
Central Meridian : 14.0°
Central Parallel : 39.5°
Scale Factor : 0.99906
```

Everything except the scale factor can be confirmed from [100k Index to WWII topo maps of Italy](http://library.mcmaster.ca/maps/ww2/ww2_Italy_ndx100k.htm) at McMaster University. From this, I developed a proj.4 definition:

```
+proj=lcc +lat_1=39.5 +lon_0=14 +k_0=0.99906 +x_0=700000 +y_0=600000 +ellps=bessel +units=m +no_defs
```

After converting alphanumeric coordinates to grid coordinates and using the above definition, I get expected values for some sample locations:

- rN175845 → 717500, 784500 → 41.1629 °N, 14.2086 °E
- rN138862 → 713800, 786200 → 41.1783 °N, 14.1646 °E

When I try to use gdalwarp to translate a georeferenced map sheet to WGS84, however, I end up with latitudes around 3-4 °N. The command line I used is:

```
gdalwarp -s_srs "+proj=lcc +lat_1=39.5 +lon_0=14 +k_0=0.99906 +x_0=700000 +y_0=600000 +ellps=bessel  +units=m +no_defs" -t_srs EPSG:4326 -r cubic -of GTiff in_modified.tif out-4326.tif
```

gdalinfo reports the following for the input file:

```
Size is 6641, 5162
Coordinate System is `'
Origin = (694095.553313978714868,954540.625156613648869)
Pixel Size = (8.495191956798934,-8.495191956798934)
Image Structure Metadata:
  INTERLEAVE=PIXEL
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (  694095.553,  954540.625) 
Lower Left  (  694095.553,  910688.444) 
Upper Right (  750512.123,  954540.625) 
Lower Right (  750512.123,  910688.444) 
Center      (  722303.838,  932614.535) 
Band 1 Block=6641x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Red
Band 2 Block=6641x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Green
Band 3 Block=6641x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Blue
```

(the sample coordinates are on another map sheet, btw.)

**Update**: a working proj.4 definition, based on mkennedy's comment below, is:

```
+proj=lcc +lat_0=39.5 +lat_1=39.5 +lon_0=14 +k_0=0.99906 +x_0=700000 +y_0=600000 +ellps=bessel +units=m +no_defs
```

Comment: Try setting lat_0 to 39.5 also (and maybe lat_2). The fact that you're getting very low latitude values makes me think that the latitude of origin is defaulting to zero.

Comment: Why don't you give your update as an answer?

Comment: Would it help? mkennedy answered it, not me.

Comment: Without an answer, the question will pop up regularily by the `Community` user, and we can not mark a new question as duplicate of this because it does not have an answer.

Comment: Although I've now added an answer, I think the issue you raise above is more of a SE design problem than something users have to work around.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Expanding on mkennedy's comment, and translating generic map terms to proj.4 parameters:

```
Projection - Lambert Conical Orthomorphic  →    +proj=lcc
Ellipsoid: Bessel 1841                     →    +ellps=bessel
False Easting : 700000                     →    +x_0=700000
False Northing : 600000                    →    +y_0=600000
Central Meridian : 14.0°                   →    +lon_0=14 
Central Parallel : 39.5°                   →    +lat_0=39.5 +lat_1=39.5
Scale Factor : 0.99906                     →    +k_0=0.99906
                       (other proj.4 terms)     +units=m +no_defs
```

which results in a working definition of

```
+proj=lcc +lat_0=39.5 +lat_1=39.5 +lon_0=14 +k_0=0.99906 +x_0=700000 +y_0=600000 +ellps=bessel +units=m +no_defs
```